# 403 Forbidden - Request forbidden @ wp-login.php. Working behind proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While uploading a client's site from local to online server, I encountered "403 Forbidden - Request forbidden by administrative rules" error. Wiped it out and did a clean install, but still got the same error. Amongst other attempts, rewrote .htaccess  using:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ -[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

All this was done from behind  the university proxy servers. While to uploading WP plugins on my WAMP server, nothing happens

Accessing it from home, there was no 403 error. It's alright. Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you enable mod_rewrite? `a2enmod mod_rewrite`

Comment: Done adding it. Will test it when I get behind a firewall. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Worked well.